# how to configure kafka topic in a spring boot project having flowable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, flowable

with flowable and kafka enable, the application runs but when i configure the kafka bean ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory. it generate an error :
<<'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaOperations' that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaOperations' in your configuration.>>

this same configuration, i do it in another project without flowable. there, it runs without any problem.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CreateRecurrenceCommand>
createRecurrenceCommandListenerContainerFactory(KafkaCreateRecurrenceErrorHandler errorHandler) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CreateRecurrenceCommand> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(createRecurrenceCommandConsumerFactory());
    factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> {
        String messageType = new String(consumerRecord.headers().lastHeader(KafkaCustomHeaders.MESSAGE_TYPE).value());
        return !ConsumedMessageType.CREATE_RECURRENCE.toString().equals(messageType);
    });
    return factory;
}


public ConsumerFactory<String, CreateRecurrenceCommand> createRecurrenceCommandConsumerFactory() {
    return generateConsumerFactory(CreateRecurrenceCommand.class, AppConstants.CREATE_RECURRENCE);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

private  ConsumerFactory<String, T> generateConsumerFactory(Class clazz, String groupId) {
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(defaultConsumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties());

```
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            groupId);
    ErrorHandlingDeserializer<T> errorHandlingDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>((topic, data) -> {
        try {
            if (data == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return objectMapper.readValue(new String(data), clazz);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new DeserializationException("Failed to deserialise", data, false, e);
        }
    });
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), errorHandlingDeserializer);
}
```

in this code was expecting to filter a specific topic message: CREATE_RECURRENCE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is "flowable", but looks like you try to configure everything yourself, not relying on Spring Boot auto-configuration. For that purpose consider to change the name of your `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to the `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`.